# Convert member ids to elements

Tags: c#, revit-api, .net-4.8

Not sure what I'm doing wrong here. The code runs but nothing happens. I'm trying to get a parameter from each element in the assembly.

```
View _ActiveView = doc.ActiveView;
bool IsAssemblyView = _ActiveView.IsAssemblyView;
ElementId _AssemblyId = _ActiveView.AssociatedAssemblyInstanceId;
var assemblyInstance = doc.GetElement(_AssemblyId) as AssemblyInstance;
if (assemblyInstance != null)
{
    List<Element> elementIdsList = new List<Element>();
    var el = assemblyInstance.GetMemberIds() as Element;
    elementIdsList.Add(el);
    foreach (Element assemElement in elementIdsList)
    {
        var test = assemElement;
        if (test != null)
        {
            if(test.IsValidObject)
            {
                var test2 = assemElement.get_Parameter(BuiltInParameter.FABRICATION_PRODUCT_DATA_PRODUCT).AsString();
                TaskDialog td = new TaskDialog("Assembly Instance Results");
                td.MainContent = test2.ToString();
                td.Show();
             }
         }
     }
 }
```

Comment: Have you tried using your debugger?

Comment: The GetMemberIds() function doesn't return a single Element, it returns a set of ElementIds. So you can't cast it directly to Element.